# WebBrowser control gives the error INET_E_DOWNLOAD_FAILURE

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, webbrowser-control, iwebbrowser2

I am using extended web browser control in my application. I am getting the error as `"INET_E_DOWNLOAD_FAILURE" (i.e - 2146697208)` and it closes the form and gives error message  as "The download of the specified resource has failed".
What may be the cause that this error occurs?

Comment: When do you get that error? What have you tried?

Comment: when I move from one page to next page. It fires NavigationError event of the WebBrowser. In that status code is -2146697208. I went through the MSDN but i got only reason of this error but not the solution and I am also not getting that where I am doing wrong.

Comment: Does the problem only exhibit itself in the web browser control? Are you able to reproduce it in an IE instance?

Answer (score 1):

your tcp connection is being reset. that caused the error. It may be done by outside of your application i.e firewall, ISP policy... or inside it like closing the connection is part of your code.